# Make additional wordpress profile fields uneditable

Tags: wordpress, profile

I have created extra profile fields for WP users but I want to make sure they are only editable by admins, is this possible?

Thnaks
Pam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding the fields, you need to check if logged in user has admin capabilities or not.

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    /* A user with admin privileges */
} else {
    /* A user without admin privileges */
}
```

accordingly you can show/hide the fields as per the user role.